# A basis for space of spline of degree k

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation-theory, spline

how can i proof space of spline of degree k on $[x_0,x_n]$ with knots:
$$x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n,$$
have a basis like this:
$$\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^k,(x-x_1)^k_+,(x-x_2)^k_+,\ldots,(x-x_{n-1})^k_+\}.$$

remark:

$$(x-x_i)^k_+=\left\{\begin{array}{2}(x-x_i)^k& x>x_i\\0& x\leq x_i\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Do you place a condition $n \ge k$  ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, does not need this condition. "$n$" shows how many partition i want to approximate a function, and "$k$" shows degree of polynomial approximate that function in $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kincaid D., Cheney W. *Numerical analysis*, Chapter 6:

A *natural spline* of degree $2m+1$ is a function $s\in C^{2m}(\mathbb{R})$
that reduces to a polynomial of degree $\leq2m+1$ in each inner interval
and to a polynomial of degree **at most $m$** in $(-\infty,t_{1})$ and
$(t_{n},\infty)$.

**Theorem.** Every natural spline can be represented using truncated power functions
as follows
$$
s(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\alpha_{k}x^{k}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{i}(x-x_{i})_{+}^{2m+1}
$$
with the coefficient conditions,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{i}x_{i}^{k}=0,\qquad k=0,1,\ldots m
$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer @rych. Consider spline $s$ of degree $k=2m+1$ for nodes $x_0<\cdots<x_n$ in **whole line** $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $[x_0,x_n]$.

Definition of spline:
\begin{array}{l}
1.\qquad s_i(x)=s(x)|_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}\in\mathbb{P}_{2m+1},\qquad i=0,1,\ldots,n-1,\\
2.\qquad s\in\mathbb{C}^{2m}(\mathbb{R}).
\end{array}
Definition of **natural spline** based on "*Numerical Mathematics*" by A. Quarteroni, page 357 :
$$s^{(i)}(x_0)=s^{(i)}(x_n)=0,\quad i=m+1,\ldots,2m.\qquad (*)$$
$s_0\in\mathbb{P}_{2m+1}$ and $s_0\in\mathbb{C}^{2m}(\mathbb{R})$.

Consider taylor expansion of $s_0$ at $x_0$:
$$\begin{align}
s_0(x)=&\sum_{i=0}^{2m}{\frac{s_0^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i}+\left[\frac{s^{(2m+1)}(x_0+)-s^{(2m+1)}(x_0-)}{(2m+1)!}\right](x-x_0)^{2m+1}\\
\stackrel{(*)}{=}& p_m(x)+b_0(x-x_0)^{2m+1},\qquad x\in[x_0,x_1].
\end{align}$$.
How can i proof $s|_{(-\infty,x_0],[x_n,\infty)}\in\mathbb{P}_m$?